# Which TCP and UDP ports are required to run an Ethereum client?

Tags: network, firewalls, port-numbers

The [geth CLI options](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options) suggest that per default the client listens on TCP port 30303. [This page](https://eth.wiki/en/fundamentals/enode-url-format), additionally suggests that UDP port 30301 is used for node discovery.

Is this all that is required or are there any additional ports in use?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Ethereum clients use a **listener (TCP)** port and a **discovery (UDP**) port, both on **30303** by default.

If you need to run **JSON-RPC**, you'll also need **TCP** port **8545**. **Note** that JSON-RPC port should not be opened to the outside world, because from there you can do admin operations.

All client's ports can be customized from the default.

If you want geth/eth to find UPnP, you'll also want that enabled on your router. That's just so it can listen on a port, not necessary if you've already manually opened/routed them.

About the wiki page you linked, it reports actually just an example:

> **If the TCP and UDP (discovery) ports differ**, the UDP port is specified
>   as query parameter *discport*.
>
> In the following **example**, the node URL describes a node with IP
>   address 10.3.58.6, TCP listening port 30303 and UDP discovery port
>   30301.

I think this misunderstanding is spreading also because of the behavior of the **bootnode** util. In fact, it uses 30301 as default UDP discovery port.

Note: geth will use IPv6 as a priority if it is available which may cause problems if you assume it is listening to the IPv4 address.

Comment: Make sure you allow outbound over TCP/30303 too.

Comment: I have both of those ports opened and yet I cannot sync. It appears that geth is attempting to connect to peers through other TCP ports. See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26652/geth-connectivity-behind-a-firewall

Comment: And make sure you activelly block inbount JSON-RPC (8545) 
https://etherscan.io/address/0x957cd4ff9b3894fc78b5134a8dc72b032ffbc464#comments

Comment: So, is TCP 30303 required to be open for INCOMMING connection when simply running the geth client? I just want to have the most current blockchain state / data on my local system, I have no interest in mining. Do I still have to open 30303 for incomming traffic?