# Which firewall settings should I use for Geth as a non-miner using Linux Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: go-ethereum

Which firewall settings should I use for Geth as a non-miner using Linux Ubuntu 15.10?

Is there a way to check that the firewall settings are correct? If so, how do I check and set the firewall settings in the Terminal?

Should I use ufw and iptables and if so, how?

**If someone has a one-liner CLI command for iptables that would be great.**

Any official recommendations from core devs or other skilled coders with  expertise regarding recommended firewall settings?

These are my current iptables settings. Output from sudo iptables -L

http://pasted.co/288f28f6

Vesa

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to forward both [TCP and UDP port 30303](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/809/which-tcp-and-udp-ports-are-required-to-run-an-ethereum-client) for Geth to work.

The simplest thing to do would be just to open these ports to all traffic, which I imagine is what most people do. If you don't want to do that, then you could try confining traffic to certain peers, but that would require you to:

- Open the ports to all traffic;
- Wait for a set of peers to be found, and check their addresses using `admin.peers`;
- Restrict traffic to those addresses using a firewall ruleset.

However, given the likely transient nature of those peers, you'd end up having to regularly change your ruleset.

Comment: Hi Richard. Do you have a CLI on-liner for iptables per chance? Now I have just enabled ufw and ipconfig without making any changes from the default and I wonder what to do next.

Comment: These are my current iptables settings. Output from sudo iptables -L http://pasted.co/288f28f6

Comment: I don't believe there are any official recommendations for firewall settings. What are you trying to achieve? What firewall settings do you use for other non-Ethereum applications? What traffic do you want to block? At the minute your settings are permissive - connecting to the Ethereum network should just work. I should have asked these questions before posting my answer! :)