# Nodes from two different networks not operable on a private blockchain

Tags: private-blockchain, connections

This is how my setting looks:

[image]

H2 and H4 are on separate networks. They have private IPs and not routable from outside the network. How do I make these two systems as peers so that they operate on the same private blockchain network? I tried using Public IP in the `enode URI` with the `addPeer()` function but the connection was not successful.

**Edit:**

As @Badr suggested, `--nat` with `extip` worked, but this cannot be used for connecting two systems with the same public IP i.e., the public IP cannot be translated to two private IPs. I tried using a different port # but the connection wasn't successful. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: does the router support Upnp?

Comment: @Badr Yes, it supports Upnp.

Comment: i didn't understand that you have tow separate  networks(as in the figure) with the same public ip?

Comment: how do you add nodes? did you get the info using admin.nodeInfo to check ip? did you tried --nat upnp or any

Comment: @Badr the two separate networks have different public ips. My problem is that I can do NAT and assign this public ip only to one of the systems in that network.

Comment: if i understood --nat extip worked for you to connect the 2 nodes in different networks but the problem occurs when you want to add an additional node from the previous networks?

Comment: @Badr Yes. That's exactly my problem.

Comment: what is the result of admin.nodeInfo in H3,H4

Comment: after starting them with --nat any or  upnp ?

Answer (score 3):

Ethereum clients use a listener (TCP) port and a discovery (UDP) port, both on 30303 by default.

[Which TCP and UDP ports are required to run an Ethereum client?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/809/which-tcp-and-udp-ports-are-required-to-run-an-ethereum-client)

as a firt try use the option

```
  --nat value       NAT port mapping mechanism (any|none|upnp|pmp|extip:<IP>) (default: "any")
```

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options

as a second choice :
I think you should make some NAT redirection at the routers level.
you need to forward the ports(default) 30303 and 8545(RPC) ports to the Hx machines

on R1

128.195.4.119:30303=>10.0.1.3:30303

128.195.4.119:8545=>10.0.1.3:8545

on R2

128.143.7.21:30303 =>192.168.1.1:30303

128.143.7.21:8545=>192.168.1.1:8545

then just use the public address when adding peers to the ethereum clients e.g enode://*******:128.143.7.21:30303

aditional information in the [official doc](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/enode-url-format) we found this :

> In the following example, the node URL describes a node with IP
>   address 10.3.58.6, TCP listening port 30303 and UDP discovery port
>   30301.
>
> enode://6f8a80d14311c39f35f516fa664deaaaa13e85b2f7493f37f6144d86991ec012937307647bd3b9a82abe2974e1407241d54947bbb39763a4cac9f77166ad92a0@10.3.58.6:30303?discport=30301

in this case consider to forward the port 30301 too.

Comment: `--nat` with `extip` worked, but this cannot be used for connecting two systems with the same public ip. I tried using a different port # but the connection wasn't successful. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

How did you build the H5 node? In particular, you should be careful in not copying the ethereum wholesale. Closer to the point:

- the `nodekey` file uniquely identifies your node.
- it prevents a node from connecting back to itself.
- if the same key is placed into 2 different nodes, these nodes will not connect to each other as they believe their are the same machine.

A test to make from H2:

- stop Geth
- delete `nodekey` file
- start Geth
- `addPeer(H5)`