# What's limiting my peer count?

Tags: peers, devp2p

I see on [ethstats](https://ethstats.net/) that some node are connected to 100, or even 500+ peers. 
I figured I'd try to increase my peer counts, e.g., in the hope of getting blocks and transactions broadcasted more widely faster.

I use geth --maxpeers=70 , but then, when I go to the geth console (e.g., geth attach), it seems I'm only connected to 35 peers. Where does the limitation come from? How does the node stop accepting peers?

Should I manually call admin.addPeer to add another bunch of peers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being connected to 35 peers is usually more than enough. What are you trying to achieve that makes you want to be connected to more nodes?

I assume you are using a computer at home which usually is connected via a router to the internet, maybe even behind a firewall that limits possible connections further. This might limit the number of nodes that you are connected to. [As outlined in the wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network#how-peers-are-found), geth connects to some bootnodes which then tell your geth some other nodes that they know on startup. In order to allow incoming connections to your geth node pro-actively, geth supports [UPnP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play) but most routers have it disabled. Alternatively you could activate port forwarding to your geth machine on the router for TCP port 30303 and UDP port 30301 [as described in this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/810/16). If you are behind a very strict firewall that limits both TCP and UDP, you might have to setup a [VPN or port forwarding tunnel](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/3gfxo0/help_starting_geth_behind_firewall/) to allow for more connections.

Comment: I'm hosting my node on an EC2 machine, I did open 30303 TCP, maybe it's limited to so little because I didn't open 30301?

Comment: Try UDP port 30301

Comment: I have deployed my nodes on digital ocean droplets. They all have the same configuration, but different nodes find different peer counts. What could it be?

Answer (score -1):

I added a rile for port forwarding from external IP port 30303 to internal IP port 30303 on a DLink and my peers jumped from 2 to 15 in a matter of 3 seconds.