# Defining "listen," "listenaddr" and "discovery" ports from admin.nodeinfo?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, javascript, node-discovery, port-numbers

f you type "admin.nodeInfo" at the javascript console, you will see:

```
 listenAddr: "[::]:<value>",
  name: "Geth/v1.6.1-stable-021c3c28/linux-amd64/go1.8.1",
  ports: {
    discovery: <value>,
    listener: <value>
  },
```

(along with a bunch of other stuff, of course.)

So we have these three ports: listenAddr, listener, discovery.  What does each one of them mean in this context.

I am *not* asking about the RPC port or the websockets port.  I am specifically asking about the thing that I just mentioned.

Comment: Are your discovery and listener ports the same?

Comment: @0xcaff According to the readout above, yes.  But this is essentially where my question is going.  Once I learn what the differences are, I may be able to learn how to change them, and what purpose that might serve.

Comment: @stone212 did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: @significance No I don't think I did and I stopped using geth more than a year ago.  But I learned a lot since May of 2017 so if you have a question that relates to this maybe I can answer?

Comment: @stone212 thanks for the offer! i think i did get to the bottom of it. it's super confusing because geth uses 30303/tcp for port comms and 30303/udp for kademlia discovery. i'll write it up below when i get a mo...

Answer (score 1):

There are basically three important ports. The first is discovery port, and other two are listener ports:

1. Discovery port: (default is 30303). This port is used for connecting to other geth nodes.
2. RPC port: (default is 8545). This port is used to send JSON-rpc requests to the geth client.
3. Websocket port: (default is 8546) You can connect to geth client using websockets.

All of them are independent process and hence cannot be run on same ports.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to reply but this does not speak to my question at all.  My question is what about the "listenAddr" and "listener" values that I find with "admin.nodeInfo" and how do they relate to the Discovery port? I've edited my post for more clarity.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/809/which-tcp-and-udp-ports-are-required-to-run-an-ethereum-client

this could help you surely

Comment: Akshay I appreciate the effort but that post mentions that there exist a listener and a discovery port.  But from my OP you see that I knew that already.  It does say that they can be the same, which is nice, although I wasn't really in doubt about that.

Answer (score 0):

listenAddr is an address , i.e. contains IP+port number

listener is only a port number

discovery is also port number for finding new peers

---

The word `listener` has a meaning of a connecting gate, for example,this is another piece of ethereum's source ('node/node.go'):

```
    ipcListener net.Listener // IPC RPC listener socket to serve API requests
    httpListener  net.Listener // HTTP RPC listener socket to server API requests
    wsListener net.Listener // Websocket RPC listener socket to server API requests
```

In `Go` `Listener` is a standard type:

```
A Listener is a generic network listener for stream-oriented protocols.

Multiple goroutines may invoke methods on a Listener simultaneously.

    type Listener interface {
            // Accept waits for and returns the next connection to the listener.
            Accept() (Conn, error)

            // Close closes the listener.
            // Any blocked Accept operations will be unblocked and return errors.
            Close() error

            // Addr returns the listener's network address.
            Addr() Addr
    }
```

This is the meaning of the word `listener` , but `ListenAddr` is the full address of the socket. it is defined in Linux kernel as this struct:

```
#include <netinet/in.h>

struct sockaddr_in {
    short            sin_family;   // e.g. AF_INET
    unsigned short   sin_port;     // e.g. htons(3490)
    struct in_addr   sin_addr;     // see struct in_addr, below
    char             sin_zero[8];  // zero this if you want to
};
```

The fields `sin_addr` and `sin_port` together is the variable `listenAddr`, in fact, this is what the method `Addr()` should return.

But in Ethereum code, by saying `listener` they don't refer to the `Interface listener` nor the object that implements listener interface, they refer to the `port number`.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?  Is "listener" ALWAYS the port number that goes into "listenAddr" or are they unrelated?  And saying that something is an address or a port number does not explain what it is or how it is different from other addresses or port numbers.  If you edit your answer to answer the question, I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: @stone212 I kind of tried to explain, check if you understand it

Comment: I do not.  The last paragraph is the first part that seems to relate to the question.  The only parts that you mentioned that talk about the terms I ask, only repeat what you said earlier.  Thank you for taking time but this is not in *any* remote way an answer to my question.

Comment: @stone212 it is, you just don't understand anything of what I just said. You should read about TCP/IP protocol and about network programming. Only then you will understand it.

Comment: I think maybe you are confusing this with another answer you maybe wrote?  This not related to networking, definitely not TCP/IP.  The question was about the definition of “listen,” “listenaddr” and “discovery” as they relate to the output of "admin.nodeinfo" at the javascript console.  It's okay.  I sometimes think I am on a different thread also.

Comment: @stone212 no, your question is more about networking. I recall, you should read TCP/IP, but probably more about what a socket is. If you name `listenAddr` a port then you don't understand that an address in the internet is composed of 2 things, and IP address and a port number. Otherwise you wouldn't call `listenAddr` a port if you knew that. Also, double colon in your example means it is an IPv6 address and it has null value, that's the notation used to express and address full of zeros. Your question is incorrect due to this, there are not 3 ports here, only 2 ports.

Comment: I am not going to use chat to argue.  But I have been in DevOps for years so the issue is not misunderstanding TCP/IP.  It's Ethereum I don't understand. :)  If you want to have another try to answer the question, okay.  If not, that's also okay.  Thank you for trying.