# How much faster is it to sync the FULL blockchain with --cache=1024?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, synchronization, benchmark

Running Geth with [`--cache=1024`](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/4210/42) is recommended to be able to sync the blockchain faster (since the default is only `--cache=16`.

I want to have the full blockchain (all past transaction data) so do not want to use [`--fast`](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1845/42).

How much faster is it to sync the full blockchain from the start using `geth --cache=1024` than just `geth`?  Have any benchmarks been performed on this?

Comment: Interesting would alos be the _why_ it is faster, or even which cache _value_ is the optimum.

Answer (score 1):

First the Ethereum blockchain is growing and growing at a faster pace. It would possibly reach 40Gb in no time. Thus allocating 1GB cache (cache--1024) is still not enough, but the syncing will go on, the time to sync depends on the following factors:

**1. Connectivity**

**2. Power supply**

**3. Device specifications**,  Normally you need at least a 2Gb RAM, 256 Gb hard disk for dedicated use only for Ethereum. Typically it takes about 10 hours to 15 days to sync depending on the above mentioned factors.

Thank you

Comment: The `cache` value in `geth` is a value in MB; 1024 thus results in the allocation of ~1 GB for internal caching. Also, assuming adequate power to begin with, how does the power supply affect syncing time?

Answer (score 0):

as i understand you may only sync using fast from an empty database . From then on you must not use this option. If though you have not sync your database for several months it may be quicker to rebuild using fast rather than ..how shall we say top up.. without this option. I would always run the cache option at the largest value your machine will allow independent of whether you are using fast or not..but I an not sure of this ..