# Why is Geth's "fast" sync now the default, whereas before it wasn't?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, fast-sync

As of version [1.6.0](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.6.0), the default method used by Geth for syncing the chaindata is "fast":

> The default sync mode is --syncmode=fast, for full sync please use
>   --syncmode=full.

Previously, the default was "full", with the user having to explicitly pass the `--fast` flag to bring about a "fast" sync.

In [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1902/52) to a previous question, [Why isn't fast sync the default?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1845/why-isnt-fast-sync-the-default), it was stated that:

> ...Fast sync indeed has one additional weakness compared to full sync.
>   As long as an attacker can keep you isolated from the main chain (e.g.
>   infect your router), **it may construct an arbitrary state that your
>   node will believe**

Is this weakness no longer the case, and if so, why not?

Comment: I think I'm not qualified to _answer_ this question, but the Ethereum blockchain is in a really bad shape and a full synchronization takes weeks on commodity hardware. Thus, the full sync mode should only be used by users knowing what they are doing. I agree this _should_ be the default mode for running a full node, but the spam attacks in 2016 make this close to impossible and this creates a usability mess.

Comment: Understood - thanks @5chdn. That all makes sense - I hadn't thought about it in this way, and it's a shame that this is the case :-\

Comment: @5chdn I did a Geth "fast" sync this week and I found that my internet speed really didn't matter at all, instead the bottleneck was my platter HDD - it was actually syncing only 1.2x faster than real-time. When I switched to my NVMe SSD it was syncing at 80x real-time. If these are the speeds I get with "fast", how long would a "full" sync take given the same hardware (HDD vs SSD)?

Answer (score 2):

The default is now "snap" sync which completes in about 4 or 5 hours for me on a SATA SSD.