# Is fast sync still safe in geth?

Tags: go-ethereum

Does the security of fast sync depend on pow? Now that eth uses pos, is it still safe to use fast sync? refer to this:[Why is Geth's "fast" sync now the default, whereas before it wasn't?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15562/why-is-geths-fast-sync-now-the-default-whereas-before-it-wasnt/149837?noredirect=1#comment168012_149837)