# Optimal sync mode for running an ethereum node that can process transactions

Tags: transactions, blockchain, synchronization, nodes, fast-sync

I need to run a local ethereum node, I've downloaded mist wallet but I've had some issues. I have to redownload the whole blockchain again, and I noticed that the problems I had could be related to the sync mode.

Is there a difference in performance when using different type of sync mode for getting balance of accounts and sending transactions?

Or is it once the blockchain is fully downloaded the sync mode doesn't affect the interactions with the network?

Any pointing in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: as a side note, if you need full node abilities you must use `full`.

Comment: thanks @OrryVandermeulen - what are the full node abilities exactly?

Comment: Take a look at the second bullet in [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1902/32011) answer, it applies to `light` as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per geth help document there are 3 ways you can do sync to network:

--syncmode full: Geth client will download Block header + Block data + full Validation [Is called eth full node]

--syncmode fast: Geth client will download Block header + Block data + validate for last 1k transactions.

--syncmode light: Geth client will download Current state + Asks nodes for as its need. [Light node [It will request missing blocks from full nodes]

You can change syncmode my specifying --syncmode along with command prompt. fast is good. But if you dont have time and space try to use light.

Comment: I'd add that `--syncmode fast` is also called a full node. honestly if syncing from scratch there's no need to use the `full` mode it will just waste a lot of time and cpu. source: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/15326#issuecomment-441997224