# Can't sync block

Tags: synchronization, nodes

I have a problem about block syncing, in the answer [Ethereum Node Stuck, Can't Sync](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/ethereum-node-stuck-cant-sync) I didn't find a answer to my problem. 
I follow @BokkyPooBah answers, it shows my network is successful.

[image: it shows my result follow the guides]

But geth still did not start sync and stop at

[image: geth just stop there]

From the pic I am sure my network is correct, but I don't know what's the problem. Any Ideas, I appreciate it. My OS is centos 6.6.