# Synchronisation using geth; DAO fork-check, dropping is the only message recieved

Tags: go-ethereum, the-dao, synchronization, hardforks

I'm attempting to synchronise with the blockchain using geth on Win7 64bit.

Presently pretty much all I'm getting is repeats of the same message; `timed
    out DAO fork-check, dropping` (see bottom).

Every now and then I get something like:

```
I0906 15:30:04.029772 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1087] Peer de471bccee3d0422 [
hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 13.560187447s]: head
header set (item 0) broke chain ordering: requested 1395022, got 2209108
```

Earlier on geth shut down on its own, I've since restarted. It looks like there is confusion over the block geth is requesting and the one served by the network...

**Is there something obvious I'm not doing?**

**Is this expected?**

**What debugging steps should I take?**

```
I0906 15:17:15.469813 eth/handler.go:295] Peer d64f779684a3986e [eth/63]: timed
out DAO fork-check, dropping
I0906 15:17:27.079477 eth/handler.go:295] Peer a979fb575495b8d6 [eth/63]: timed
out DAO fork-check, dropping
I0906 15:17:37.041047 eth/handler.go:295] Peer 1637a970d987ddb8 [eth/63]: timed
out DAO fork-check, dropping
I0906 15:17:48.289690 eth/handler.go:295] Peer 450f0ea6d5b5bb05 [eth/63]: timed
out DAO fork-check, dropping
I0906 15:17:55.155083 eth/handler.go:295] Peer 3806e6f2b68b6e8b [eth/63]: timed
out DAO fork-check, dropping
I0906 15:18:27.007905 eth/handler.go:295] Peer 30dc547dbd116454 [eth/63]: timed
out DAO fork-check, dropping
I0906 15:18:29.160028 eth/handler.go:295] Peer 49eb90bacc21836d [eth/63]: timed
out DAO fork-check, dropping
I0906 15:18:56.982619 eth/handler.go:295] Peer 1637a970d987ddb8 [eth/63]: timed
out DAO fork-check, dropping
I0906 15:19:12.209490 eth/handler.go:295] Peer bb50c8d7c77adf15 [eth/63]: timed
out DAO fork-check, dropping
I0906 15:19:28.016394 eth/handler.go:295] Peer 30dc547dbd116454 [eth/63]: timed
out DAO fork-check, dropping
I0906 15:19:51.930762 eth/handler.go:295] Peer bf83662ffd07c1cd [eth/63]: timed
out DAO fork-check, dropping
I0906 15:19:52.585800 eth/handler.go:295] Peer 53368afb96ab78d4 [eth/63]: timed
out DAO fork-check, dropping
I0906 15:19:59.847215 eth/handler.go:295] Peer 30dc547dbd116454 [eth/63]: timed
out DAO fork-check, dropping
I0906 15:20:24.219609 eth/handler.go:295] Peer 1118980bf48b0a36 [eth/63]: timed
out DAO fork-check, dropping
I0906 15:20:54.413336 eth/handler.go:295] Peer 7cb3f7c58572e50c [eth/63]: timed
out DAO fork-check, dropping
I0906 15:21:28.244271 eth/handler.go:295] Peer 2c2fabac9ef11438 [eth/63]: timed
out DAO fork-check, dropping
I0906 15:22:11.317735 eth/handler.go:295] Peer 390cc42f79d44232 [eth/63]: timed
out DAO fork-check, dropping
I0906 15:22:13.949885 eth/handler.go:295] Peer d64f779684a3986e [eth/63]: timed
out DAO fork-check, dropping
I0906 15:22:24.773504 eth/handler.go:295] Peer 30dc547dbd116454 [eth/63]: timed
out DAO fork-check, dropping
I0906 15:22:28.993746 eth/handler.go:295] Peer 60aa98bd34813843 [eth/63]: timed
out DAO fork-check, dropping
I0906 15:22:39.275334 eth/handler.go:295] Peer 69bfa214a36e0e4d [eth/63]: timed
out DAO fork-check, dropping
I0906 15:23:02.228647 eth/handler.go:295] Peer f6aa7c1d67d3b088
```

etc...

UPDATE:

Presently trying again as recommended [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2769/820).