# What is JITVM in Geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, jitvm

What is JITVM, what it is used for and what is its relation with `--fast`flag?

And also how is it different than EVM. Are they both same if not than what's the difference?

Comment: Related https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4212/what-optimizations-does-geths-jitvm-do

Answer (score 1):

It Enables de JIT Virtual Machine.

EVM is the Ethereum Virtual Machine, the default one.

> The EVM’s internals are pretty simple; it has a single run loop which
>   will attempt to execute the instruction at the current Program Counter
>   (PC in short). Within this loop the Gas is calculated for each
>   instruction, memory is expanded if necessary and executes the
>   instruction if the preamble succeeds. This will continue on until the
>   VM either finishes gracefully or returns with an error by throwing an
>   exception (e.g. out-of-gas).

And In Case of JIT VM:

> The JIT-EVM takes a different approach to running EVM byte-code and is
>   by definition initially slower than the byte-code VM. Before the VM
>   can run any code it must first compile the byte-code in to components
>   that can be understood by the JIT VM.
>
> The initialisation- and execution procedure is done in 3-steps:
>
> We check whether there’s a JIT program ready to be run using the hash
>   of the code — H(C) is used as an identifier to identify the program;
>   if a program was found we run the program and return the result; if no
>   program was found we run the byte-code and we compile a JIT program in
>   the background.

The `--fast` flag is for "fast syncing" by not processing the complete blockchain with every transaction since the beginning, but syncing by just downloading the transaction receipts along the blocks, creating a recent state database complete for this purpose.

Source: https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/06/02/go-ethereums-jit-evm/