# Geth client shows old balance, can't transfer eth

Tags: go-ethereum

I recently transferred some eth from my account to another (Kraken specifically to exchange it). That worked, then a couple days later I tried to transfer more, the geth console returned the same output (some sort of transaction id), but the other account never received it. I tried removing my ~/.ethereum folder and restarting geth to see if it was a problem with its state, but that didnt't help. Now it shows the old balance (before my first successful transaction), and I still can't transfer eth. Etherchain.org and others reflect the correct value.

Any ideas what would cause this? Here is my geth version:

```
Geth
Version: 1.4.6-stable
Protocol Versions: [63 62 61]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.6.1
OS: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=/usr/lib/go-1.6
```

Comment: please wait till your blockchain is fully synced, see http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/4222/87

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As 5chdn said, you have to wait till your `chaindata` is completely synced.

There are multiple ways you can speed up the process

1. use `geth --fast`
2. Import the chain data
3. Copy/Paste the chain data folder.

[This answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-get-a-geth-node-to-download-the-blockchain-quickly) explains a lot

Comment: From experience, and from the answer you link to, using `geth import <filename>` isn't particularly fast... :(

Comment: Is there a way to reason about the time it will take to complete? What's strange is, when I made my first transaction a few days ago, I had only run geth client for a few hours maybe, and now its been many times that but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @wjimenez5271 eta for completion is depends upon many factors like speed of internet, you computers gnu/cpu performance no of peers connected etc.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks yeah, i have mentioned some ways for getting sync.

Comment: OK great, it finally completed, just took much longer than previously. This was helpful background information. Thanks