# how do I know when my testnet node is fully synchronized, significance out output text

Tags: testnets

I've started my geth node with the following command:

```
$ geth --testnet --fast --cache=512 console
```

Now my console looks something like this:

[image]

How will I know when my node is fully synchronized?

```
INFO [07-20|13:32:48] Imported new state entries    count=384  elapsed=14.509ms  processed=1610372 pending=101560
INFO [07-20|13:32:48] Imported new block receipts   count=282  elapsed=66.980ms  number=1317825    hash=1085ad…37a592 ignored=0
```

Why are those two entries above different?

Is it that `Imported new block receipts` represents a block and `Imported new state entries` represents a transaction?

Is this node, as it was initiated with the command above, by default mining and proposing blocks to the network?

Comment: You can look at a [block explorer](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/) to see what the latest block number is. When the processed number reaches that you have finished synching.

Comment: When syncing `eth.syncing` will output some stats, when it is not syncing it will return false. But at the beginning until it find some peers it will also return false, so you should check that `eth.blockNumber` is non zero.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do you know your db is synced in geth?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4222/how-do-you-know-your-db-is-synced-in-geth)

Comment: open your ethereum app with skipping sync, and see state of your block sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pretty sure the answer is that the output of `geth --testnet --cache=512 console` starts looking like this:

[image]

but this is just my conjecture, if someone more knowledgable that I could validate this answer that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the output text of your node, it is significant and gives all the information you need to know when your testnet node is fully synchronized:

- Look for line with text "Import new state entries"
- on that same line look for "processed = value #1". That value #1 is 263.000.000 (28 Oct 2020) on testnet Ropsten and is always increasing. That value must reach the maximum value of the network (increasing daily), otherwise the node is not in sync.
- on same line look also for "pending = value #2". That value #2 must reach zero, otherwise the node is not in sync.

It will only finish processing those "state entries" when value #2 reaches zero and then you will see the text "Fast sync complete" <=> the node is finally in sync.

Also the output of > eth.syncing on the attached console will be "false".