# Can you explain some fields in geth logs "Imported new state entries"?

Tags: go-ethereum, logs

Here is a part of logs during geth syncing:

```
INFO [04-13|05:01:20] Imported new state entries               count=1152 elapsed=6.026ms   processed=21622419 pending=7126  retry=0   duplicate=28494 unexpected=55593
INFO [04-13|05:01:20] Imported new state entries               count=768  elapsed=4.248ms   processed=21623187 pending=7420  retry=0   duplicate=28494 unexpected=55593
INFO [04-13|05:01:21] Imported new state entries               count=768  elapsed=3.480ms   processed=21623955 pending=8237  retry=0   duplicate=28494 unexpected=55593
INFO [04-13|05:01:23] Imported new state entries               count=1920 elapsed=10.053ms  processed=21625875 pending=7894  retry=0   duplicate=28494 unexpected=55593
INFO [04-13|05:01:23] Imported new state entries               count=768  elapsed=3.886ms   processed=21626643 pending=7584  retry=0   duplicate=28494 unexpected=55593
INFO [04-13|05:01:25] Imported new state entries               count=1152 elapsed=6.621ms   processed=21627795 pending=7054  retry=0   duplicate=28494 unexpected=55593
INFO [04-13|05:01:26] Imported new state entries               count=768  elapsed=4.586ms   processed=21628563 pending=9079  retry=0   duplicate=28494 unexpected=55593
INFO [04-13|05:01:27] Imported new state entries               count=768  elapsed=11.209ms  processed=21629331 pending=9281  retry=0   duplicate=28494 unexpected=55593
INFO [04-13|05:01:28] Imported new state entries               count=768  elapsed=4.465ms   processed=21630099 pending=9035  retry=0   duplicate=28494 unexpected=55593
INFO [04-13|05:01:28] Imported new state entries               count=768  elapsed=3.731ms   processed=21630867 pending=9147  retry=0   duplicate=28494 unexpected=55593
```

Can you please explain these fields in this log:

- elapsed
- pending
- retry
- duplicate
- unexpected

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21700/what-is-the-significance-of-geth-node-output

Comment: at the end of syncing process your node is downloading the state, and state entries are the account balances. it takes much longer to download all state than all blocks and transactions