# How to find out how many blocks left to sync?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

When syncing with geth, how do you know how many blocks are left to be fully in sync?

Comment: see also this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/5761/820

Answer (score 3):

From the console, you can check the syncing info with:

```
eth.syncing
```

Which will return something like this:

```
{
  currentBlock: 4036471,
  highestBlock: 4200826,
  knownStates: 0,
  pulledStates: 0,
  startingBlock: 4028732
}
```

Pro tip: try the following to get the number without having to do any maths:

```
eth.syncing.highestBlock - eth.syncing.currentBlock
```