# Official data about synchronization time

Tags: synchronization, fast-sync, benchmark

Are there in the literature or from the Ethereum community/foundation any official benchmark about geth (or any other client, e.g. parity) initial synchronization time (with both fast and normal sync)?

### UPDATE

I noticed that this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4211/how-much-faster-is-it-to-sync-with-jitvm) contain some interesting data, but the geth versions are really old. I would like to have data for geth version > 1.8.x

### UPDATE

The [official Ethereum blog](https://blog.ethereum.org/2018/02/14/geth-1-8-iceberg%C2%B9/) contains some benchmark on time needed for geth fast synchronization with geth 1.8.0 and geth 1.7.0

Answer (score 1):

For Geth v1.9.0, look here for some new details on sync time. Describes all three modes and times including some changes that one should know about.

https://blog.ethereum.org/2019/07/10/geth-v1-9-0/

As of Aug 2, 2019 the size on disk for me was 356 GB and state entries went to 370 million. Takes a couple of days to sync with a ssd drive. Be patient.

terminalscreenshot https://ibb.co/BjtCDbW