# Ether Mist Wallet How to I open one

Tags: mist, dao, myetherwallet

I am really keen to buy some DAO before Saturday and I need to open an Ether Wallet.  The problem is (a) downloading it is taking days with little progress and (b) understanding it all is well HARD...Can someone please explain this to me very simply....

Cheers Stretch

Comment: Hi there. When you say downloading is taking days, what have you tried? Have you downloaded Mist (i.e. the wallet), which is still syncing? What specifically are you trying to understand? How the wallet works, how the DAO works, or Ethereum in general? (Or all of the above?)

Comment: Hi Richard,  Thanks for the response - initially I tried to download the https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases and this takes days so then someone said I should do the following: myetherwallet. upload keystore file (C:/USERS/X/APPDATA/LOCAL (or roaming one of the 2)/ETHEREUM/KEYSTORE) the file inside will be your wallet. upload to the website, fill your password and you can buy dao - so when I follow these instructions and try do download nothing happens - I understand what the DAO is about and what Ethereum is and where it is going and I have ether with various exchanges

Answer (score 1):

1. Create new wallet on MyEtherWallet.
2. Save Keystore File. Save password. Back up externally (USB, paper).
3. Send from Exchange to the address you created on MyEtherWallet
4. Go to The DAO tab, unlock your wallet, and choose the amount you wish to send.
5. Done!

[Help Page is Helpful](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#help) • [DAO Page](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#the-dao)

---

Alternatively, try to sync Mist. [Read the top answer here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/603/help-with-very-slow-mist-sync) on how to sync using `geth --fast` to hopefully speed along the process.

---

*disclosure: I'm co-founder of MyEtherWallet. I only answered this because you mentioned that is what you were trying to do. I would normally recommend getting Mist set up first, but you are really cutting it close now. I still recommend that you get Mist set up, even if it's after you get your DAO Tokens. It is worthwhile, especially with all the Tokens and Contracts coming around.*