# Mist not syncing properly

Tags: mist, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Hopefully someone can help me out with a problem I'm experiencing.

I created a wallet contract to which I transferred the ETH on my account. Unfortunately, a few days later I restarted Mist and initially I still saw the correct balance only having it vanishing before my eyes 0,5 seconds later. The balance on my main account also vanished.

I've tried a clean install of Mist importing the UTC-- file. But to no avail.

I've also tried to import the UTC-- file through myetherwallet.com. Which gives me control of my main account again, but not the wallet contract that should be associated with it.

> Below are the codes for my;  Main:
>   0x9724Ba43c22c735A2A0C025b90F18AD2a25798C2  Contract:
>   0xe2839b4DF4168b5FDDc813883844162Ba4A8Bc6F

I'm running Geth 1.4.10 and the ETH are forked.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help with very slow mist sync](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/603/help-with-very-slow-mist-sync)

Comment: Just import the contract again. Go do _add wallet_ and click on _import existing contract_ and just paste the public key of the contract. Should be all you need.

Answer (score 1):

The project has evolved throughout this year. Maybe you should try again with latest [Mist release](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases), and make sure to have the experimental Light Client feature enabled.