# How can I receive ETH at Mist sent from other wallet

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I want to receive ETH in my Mist account to test ETH transfer. But it doesn't work well so far.
I tried to send ETH to my Mist account from other bitcoin and ETH transfer service. but I cannot receive ETH account on Mist. and account deposit still zero for several days. How can I receive ETH on my Mist.

Do I need some action on Mist??

Comment: Have you synced Mist? http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/603/help-with-very-slow-mist-sync

Answer (score 3):

First, check whether your transaction executed successfully using a blockchain explorer like https://etherscan.io/ or https://etherchain.org/.

If your account balance includes the transfer, then it is most likely a problem with the syncing of your blockchain data, as `@eth`'s mentions.

If it is a syncing problem, and your computer runs on a hard disk drive (HDD) and not a solid state drive (SSD), the reason for your syncing problem is due to the recent [attacks on the Ethereum network](https://www.bokconsulting.com.au/blog/ethereum-network-attackers-ip-address-is-traceable/). The attacker sent many many low cost transactions that caused the blockchain node clients to slow down, and the hardest hit are clients running on HDD drives.

The solution if you have a HDD drive is to either upgrade your computer to a SSD drive, or wait until the next hard fork when the node clients will attempt to remove some of the data that slows down syncing. The latest update on the upcoming hard fork can be found at [[UPDATE] Hard Fork Block Number Delay [10/31/2016]](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5afory/update_hard_fork_block_number_delay_10312016/).

If you have a SSD and more than 4 Gb RAM on your computer, clear out your old blockchain data by deleting the `chaindata` directory on your computer, or finding the `geth` executable and executing `geth removedb` to remove the old chain data. Then run Mist and it will attempt to sync again.

The default `chaindata` directory can be found in:

- Mac: `~/Library/Ethereum`
- Linux: `~/.ethereum`
- Windows: `%APPDATA%/Ethereum`

(Remember not to delete your `keystore` directory as this directory contains your private keys).

All of this assumes that you have the [latest 0.8.7 Mist (or Ethereum Wallet)](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/tag/v0.8.7).

Comment: I started yesterday with the most recent geth version (1.5.9) and >4gb ram and still it takes like for ever at around block 2400000

Comment: See http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9883/why-is-my-node-synchronization-stuck-extremely-slow-at-block-2-306-843 . Best to remove your blockchain data and fast sync. Remember to back up your keystore.

Comment: I did that :/. removed everything and started with --fast --cache=4096. Still its totally slow around block 2400000 (windows)