# Parity --warp stops syncing at block 2,626,057

Tags: synchronization, parity, warp-sync

The title says it all. I'm testing parity with `--warp pruning fast`. Was thrilled having started a node in ~10 min and synced the chain in ~1,5 hours. One day later I try to do transactions with the graphical interface (great user interface!), but I can't receive, because my sync stops at block 2,626,057. Restarted several times, but no success until I killed the `-warp` option. Now it works.

Is this normal or a specific bug of my system?

Comment: For anyone stumbling on this later on, given the block number, I think the details in [this excellent answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/9892/17829) pertaining to the low gas price network attacks & transaction spamming attacks applies.