# Parity not syncing anymore

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, parity

About 2 days ago I started to download Ethereum's blockchain with Parity. After a while, I tried to start Parity with a few flags `parity --geth --ui-interface 0.0.0.0 --ui-no-validation`, so I would be possible to run Parity UI from any localhost instance.

Right after it, the syncing velocity fell down terrifically (sometimes it was ~`30 blk/s` before):

```
2016-12-04 20:44:00  Syncing #2344834 f9ee…4664      0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s       0+    0 Qed   #2344834    7/ 8/25 peers      4 MiB db  223 KiB chain  0 bytes queue  149 KiB sync
2016-12-04 20:44:13  Syncing #2344834 f9ee…4664      0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s       0+    0 Qed   #2344834    7/ 8/25 peers      4 MiB db  223 KiB chain  0 bytes queue  630 KiB sync
2016-12-04 20:44:13  Syncing #2344834 f9ee…4664      0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s       0+    0 Qed   #2344834    7/ 8/25 peers      4 MiB db  223 KiB chain  0 bytes queue  630 KiB sync
2016-12-04 20:44:23  Syncing #2344834 f9ee…4664      0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s       0+    0 Qed   #2344834    2/ 3/25 peers      4 MiB db  223 KiB chain  0 bytes queue  709 KiB sync
2016-12-04 20:44:28  Syncing #2344843 e2d8…1c10      1 blk/s    8 tx/s   1 Mgas/s      84+    0 Qed   #2344928    2/ 2/25 peers      5 MiB db  229 KiB chain  367 KiB queue  845 KiB sync
2016-12-04 20:44:46  Syncing #2344855 68cf…6d5c      2 blk/s   25 tx/s   1 Mgas/s     740+    0 Qed   #2345604    6/ 7/25 peers      6 MiB db  268 KiB chain    3 MiB queue  527 KiB sync
2016-12-04 20:44:50  Syncing #2344855 68cf…6d5c      0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s     740+    0 Qed   #2345604    6/ 7/25 peers      6 MiB db  268 KiB chain    3 MiB queue  606 KiB sync
2016-12-04 20:44:50  Syncing #2344855 68cf…6d5c      0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s     740+    0 Qed   #2345604    6/ 7/25 peers      6 MiB db  268 KiB chain    3 MiB queue  606 KiB sync
2016-12-04 20:44:58  Syncing #2344855 68cf…6d5c      0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s     866+    0 Qed   #2345722    2/ 3/25 peers      6 MiB db  268 KiB chain    3 MiB queue  614 KiB sync
2016-12-04 20:45:05  Syncing #2344855 68cf…6d5c      0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s    1248+    0 Qed   #2346107    5/ 6/25 peers      6 MiB db  268 KiB chain    4 MiB queue  372 KiB sync
2016-12-04 20:45:16  Syncing #2344855 68cf…6d5c      0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s    1251+    0 Qed   #2346107    5/ 6/25 peers      6 MiB db  268 KiB chain    4 MiB queue  611 KiB sync
2016-12-04 20:45:30  Syncing #2344855 68cf…6d5c      0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s    1680+    0 Qed   #2346536    4/ 5/25 peers      6 MiB db  268 KiB chain    6 MiB queue  618 KiB sync
2016-12-04 20:45:35  Syncing #2344855 68cf…6d5c      0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s    1680+    0 Qed   #2346613    4/ 5/25 peers      6 MiB db  268 KiB chain    6 MiB queue  651 KiB sync
2016-12-04 20:45:52  Syncing #2344855 68cf…6d5c      0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s    2137+    0 Qed   #2346993    5/ 6/25 peers      6 MiB db  268 KiB chain    7 MiB queue  653 KiB sync
2016-12-04 20:45:52  Syncing #2344855 68cf…6d5c      0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s    2137+    0 Qed   #2347120    5/ 6/25 peers      6 MiB db  268 KiB chain    7 MiB queue  573 KiB sync
2016-12-04 20:46:03  Syncing #2344855 68cf…6d5c      0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s    2264+    0 Qed   #2347120    5/ 6/25 peers      6 MiB db  268 KiB chain    8 MiB queue  732 KiB sync
2016-12-04 20:46:03  Syncing #2344855 68cf…6d5c      0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s    2264+    0 Qed   #2347120    5/ 6/25 peers      6 MiB db  268 KiB chain    8 MiB queue  732 KiB sync
2016-12-04 20:46:16  Syncing #2344855 68cf…6d5c      0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s    2772+    0 Qed   #2347628    4/ 5/25 peers      6 MiB db  268 KiB chain    9 MiB queue  573 KiB sync
2016-12-04 20:46:38  Syncing #2344855 68cf…6d5c      0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s    3026+    0 Qed   #2347882    4/ 5/25 peers      6 MiB db  268 KiB chain   10 MiB queue  733 KiB sync
2016-12-04 20:46:38  Syncing #2344855 68cf…6d5c      0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s    3026+    0 Qed   #2347882    3/ 4/25 peers      6 MiB db  268 KiB chain   10 MiB queue  733 KiB sync
2016-12-04 20:46:38  Syncing #2344855 68cf…6d5c      0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s    3026+    0 Qed   #2347882    3/ 4/25 peers      6 MiB db  268 KiB chain   10 MiB queue  733 KiB sync
2016-12-04 20:46:38  Syncing #2344855 68cf…6d5c      0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s    3026+    0 Qed   #2347882    3/ 4/25 peers      6 MiB db  268 KiB chain   10 MiB queue  733 KiB sync
2016-12-04 20:46:48  Syncing #2344855 68cf…6d5c      0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s    3140+    0 Qed   #2348105    5/ 6/25 peers      6 MiB db  268 KiB chain   10 MiB queue  747 KiB sync
2016-12-04 20:47:05  Syncing #2344855 68cf…6d5c      0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s    3535+    0 Qed   #2348391    5/ 6/25 peers      6 MiB db  268 KiB chain   11 MiB queue    1 MiB sync
2016-12-04 20:47:05  Syncing #2344855 68cf…6d5c      0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s    3535+    0 Qed   #2348391    5/ 6/25 peers      6 MiB db  268 KiB chain   11 MiB queue    1 MiB sync
2016-12-04 20:47:15  Syncing #2344855 68cf…6d5c      0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s    3789+    0 Qed   #2348898    4/ 5/25 peers      6 MiB db  268 KiB chain   13 MiB queue  807 KiB sync
2016-12-04 20:47:26  Syncing #2344855 68cf…6d5c      0 blk/s    0 tx/s   0 Mgas/s    4296+    0 Qed   #2349152    4/ 5/25 peers      6 MiB db  268 KiB chain   14 MiB queue  807 KiB sync
```

What is the reason and how can I fix it? I tried to stop / start Parity without any flags, restarted the laptop but it didn't help.

Comment: And also related: [Why is my node synchronization stuck/extremely slow at block 2,306,843?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/9883/87)