# Account/Contract address of people responsible for Ethereum Attacks?

Tags: transactions, addresses, attacks

I believe there has been a hard fork following the DAO attack; I guess it's not possible to get the contract/account address for the person responsible, unless I am wrong and there is a way, please let me know. However, I am also aware there that there was a DDOS attack in late 2016 and there were talks for another hard fork, I am not sure whether that has happened yet or not. I am running a Geth client with full node sync, and every time it excruciating slows down around 2,400,000 blocks, which tell me the hard fork hasn't happened. If possible can someone please tell me what contract and normal account address were used for the attack?

I am writing a transaction visualisation web app for Ethereum; it will be very useful to know who the perpetrators were so I could identify them in my visualisation. Or please tell me a way to find out the attackers' contract and account addresses.

If I don't know about any other attack, it will be much appreciated if I was informed.

Comment: I came across the post regarding the slowdown of geth [syncing](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9883/why-is-my-node-synchronization-stuck-extremely-slow-at-block-2-306-843), the most popular answer contained a blog post detailing the attack and all the addresses responsible https://www.bokconsulting.com.au/blog/ethereum-network-attackers-ip-address-is-traceable/