# Time to download blockchain these days?

Tags: blockchain, synchronization

I'm trying to download the blockchain using geth. I started it around 10 days ago, without the `--fast` parameter. After about 7 days it got corrupted at block 1.800.000 or so. Then i tried starting over using the `--fast` prefix, it went a lot faster at first but now it is taking 5-10 minutes per block while previously it used to take 8 seconds per block. What causes this difference?

Not sure if i'm doing something wrong or if it's normal to take multiple weeks to download the whole blockchain?

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to Ethereum, there are two things you got to consider unlike most cryptocurrencies: Your download speed, and your processing speed. That difference you're seeing is most likely because your node is stuck processing "busier" blocks that carry more transactions and contracts. [Moreover, Ethereum has had to deal with spam attacks before](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9883/why-is-my-node-synchronization-stuck-extremely-slow-at-block-2-306-843/9892#9892), and your client still needs to process the transactions related to these attacks at some point or another.

As a reference, I was unable to get much luck with `geth` at all, as my connection is not too reliable and as a security measure, upon the tiniest sign of trouble, the fast sync will be cancelled and geth will fall back to full block verification, to the point I ended up using Parity in Geth compatibility mode so I could keep using Ethereum Wallet.

`parity --geth --warp` took just about two days or so to get the headers for the latest blocks so I could at least see the latest transactions, and around a week to process all blocks on my measly 3Mbps connection.

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on your network speed and processing power.