# geth full node taking forever to sync

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, nodes

For three days I've been trying to sync a full node. Syncing the last two days has taken about six hours a day. At this rate I won't be able to sync it. It's behind "age=3y8mo5d".

This is the command I used:
`geth --datadir /media/internal-2tb/eth --syncmode full`

Why is it taking so long? Is there a way I can speed it up so it syncs in a reasonable amount of time?

[image: syncing full node]

Comment: I think this has to do with this: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9883/why-is-my-node-synchronization-stuck-extremely-slow-at-block-2-306-843?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: If it is a mechanical disk you should be aware that they haven't been supported for several years.

Comment: @Ismael damn I didn't see that. Guess I'll just run a light node.

Comment: My node's been syncing for 3 weeks ><