# Trying and failing to create my first Ethereum wallet

Tags: wallets

About 10 days ago, I created a desktop wallet on my Mac, downloading the wallet app from the Ethereum.org site.

I was told I'll have to "sync" the wallet and go through all of the blocks before my wallet is made. I transferred my first 10 Ether from Poloniex when I got the wallet address loaded, but nothing has shown up since all the blocks aren't synced yet.  It has been 10 days, on my fastest VPN server.

Now, IU've gone from 3,000,000 blocks to less than 100, but every time it gets to less than 100, it adds another couple of hundred blocks. This seems to be what it does, not try to complete the job, just getting new blocks for my computer to work on.

It is acting like a node, not like a wallet.  How do I get my 10 Ether back?  How many weeks will it take for my wallet to actually become a wallet, not a node?

I am a newbie and just want to get my investment back. I have seen my Ether in the blockchain so I know it is somewhere, just nowhere I can get it.  please advise.  Thank you.

Evander

Answer (score 1):

You're using a full node when you're using Geth or Parity (https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/57m64h/what_is_a_full_node_exactly/d8tcthv/), so you're correct that the wallet is acting like a node.

If you're fully synced, I'm not really sure what could have gone wrong. Perhaps you could try using https://www.myetherwallet.com/ or you could try resyncing by removing the chain data and then run geth --fast

([Help with very slow mist sync](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/603/help-with-very-slow-mist-sync))

MyEtherWallet has the means to send transactions offline for you so long as you have either the

1. Keystore File (UTC / JSON)
2. Private Key
3. Mnemonic Phrase
4. Parity Phrase (Specific to the parity client, I believe)

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way I can undo this transaction top Poloniex to my desktop wallet. I just want my Ether back, and really don't want to climb further down this rabbit hole. All of this is over my head, and I expected a a wallet when I downloaded a wallet.

Comment: Go to the address you sent ether to on https://etherscan.io/ From there you should see Transactions. Poloniex's wallet is named and it should be under 'from'. If you see the address has ether in it, then you should have it in there. If you don't see it in there, than perhaps the transaction failed on Poloniex's end.