# Ethereum mist wallet not synchronising, not showing Ethereum and folder

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, mist, wallets, ether

I am a beginner at setting this up and I used a youtube tutorial to download Mist. The problem is it's not syncing the blockchains. I've tried to debug this by going to users/appdata and inside the Ethereum folder but inside there is only a geth and keystore folder.

I have sent some Ethereum to my account but cannot see it I'm assuming this is because it hasn't attempted to sync with the blockchains.

Please can someone help me as I'm totally stuck :(

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, you can check if your transaction has been made using [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io). Just replace your transaction number, as: 
https://etherscan.io/tx/[trx_number].

You should be able to see if your ETH has been sent and received. You can also check the balance of your wallet with Etherscan, you just need to enter your ETH address, as: 
https://etherscan.io/address/[your_eth_address]

If you see that both the ETH have been sent, and that your wallet indeed contains it, congrats! The operation has been successful.

Now, it takes (a lot of) time to sync your ETH wallet. If you want to accelerate it, please check this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/603/help-with-very-slow-mist-sync).

All the best!

Comment: In addition to the link you gave, it is also possible to use "geth --syncmode light" to synchronize in 20 minutes. But then it is impossible to mine.