# Sync never completes via cmdline Geth or GUI Mist wallet

Tags: mist

I have been trying to sync my machine up to mine Ether for the past few days to no success. Regardless of what version of any program I use, it always sticks around 60 percent complete and goes up about 10 blocks an hour. The first 60 percent of it only took an hour or so to download. I have tried totally removing all Ethereum related software and reinstalling to no avail.

I have a 50 down MINIMUM internet connection
I have more than enough SSD space
I have 16gb of memory
I have the newest versions of all software required.
I am running windows 8.1 x64

[image]

I appreciate any assistance!

Comment: 1,367,000 2HRS after original post.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/603/help-with-very-slow-mist-sync?noredirect=1&lq=1 Following this link now, will report back

Answer (score 1):

When i was running my ethereum wallet before the geth 1.6 was to slow, my connection is not high but i stay more than 4 days for finish the sync. And this in the Test-net, so maybe is a general problem of them.

I will also tell you that you have been having problems:

> If anyone is having geth client nodes drop offline due to the mainnet
>   attacks please update to Geth v1.6.5.

This is a communication of their twitter. So it will be better to keep waiting...