# Check balance without waiting for blockchain to sync using Mist

Tags: mist

I did not use my wallet for a few months and when I tried to transfer my ether I could not reliably see the balance. The system is taking a long time to update.

Is there anyway to avoid a client update for a MIST wallet and have some kind of wallet online which avoids a client download?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help with very slow mist sync](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/603/help-with-very-slow-mist-sync)

Comment: How is someone entitled to change my title?

Comment: I changed the title for the community to understand the question better.

Comment: Also, if the title is more descriptive (or in some cases more interesting), more people are likely to click through and read it, and potentially answer it :-)

Comment: Ok, but that is a subjective view. So anyone can just change anyone's title? If I write a title you seem to be saying someone may just change it if they disagree with it.

Comment: Not just anyone. Mods.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question "Help with very slow mist sync". Here the person asking explicitly to check an account's balance without having to synchronize a full node.

Comment: No this is not a duplicate question. The link is about how to download quicker. My question is about avoiding the Mist wallet. According to the answer etherscan.io can be used but I cannot see my balance there.

Comment: Addressing the "mods" question, I do not like just having my text changed without any discussion. What is incredible is the entire blockchain movement is about avoiding arbitrary control over data, and a website supported by blockchain activists opposes core blockchain principles.

Comment: Anyone can suggest an edit, though those suggestions have to be approved by moderators or members with enough reputation to have the requisite privilege. (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). These rules are the same for all SE boards. I understand your frustration, and imagine we've all suffered the same at some point. Try to see your question more as community property, which is there to help other members as much as it is you (again, perhaps subjective... ). If you disagree with an edit, then the comments section (or chat) is for discussion, which is what we're doing now :-)

Comment: an interesting exchnage before the moderators election. let's discuss the solution instead arguing about the title :D.

Comment: To me the entire point of blockchain methods is that data is not owned by a third party. If someone can just change the data that implies ownership. I just checked the ownership and a company called Stack Exchange which is financed by VC owns this site. This is not a community based principle and definitely not a blockchain one. It is a commercial one. In this context the only community based control would be public and that of the government. I would prefer the Government to control posts than a VC backed company under the guise of the "community." Would you approve more government control?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can achieve it using Mist, because the application is structured in such a way where it has to wait for the Blockchain to sync to latest stage before it even starts.

#### There are online wallets which helps you transact using private keys; like [myetherwallet.com](http://myetherwallet.com)

However, light clients are coming in the next Ethereum release, Metropolis. A light client is exactly what you're describing. A wallet or Ethereum (Dapp) browser that enables users to browse, receive and send transactions without having to synchronize the entire chain on a full node.

Meanwhile, you can use any Blockchain explorer like [etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io) to see your balance by entering your public key.