# Ether received via faucet is not visible in geth console

Tags: go-ethereum, testrpc, testnets, ropsten

I have ropsten network running in localhost using command :

```
geth --testnet --syncmode "fast" --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=1024  --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --bootnodes "enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303,enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303,enode://94c15d1b9e2fe7ce56e458b9a3b672ef11894ddedd0c6f247e0f1d3487f52b66208fb4aeb8179fce6e3a749ea93ed147c37976d67af557508d199d9594c35f09@192.81.208.223:30303" --verbosity=6
```

I can see its getting synced.But when I opened geth console:

```
 instance: Geth/v1.7.3-stable-4bb3c89d/linux-amd64/go1.9
 at block: 0 (Thu, 01 Jan 1970 05:30:00 IST)
 modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0
```

`at block` is not updated. By passing command `eth.syncing`

```
 {
  currentBlock: 2864241,
  highestBlock: 2864363,
  knownStates: 9349,
  pulledStates: 688,
 startingBlock: 2864149
}
```

`currentblock` was incrementing then it got stuck,then after running the first command again `currentblock` in geth console increments and stucks. But in geth testnet terminal syncing is continued just its not updated in geth console.

Comment: The main problem is about syncing, eth being not visible is an outcome of the same poblem.

Comment: But in the first terminal passing geth testnet, I can see      
  `DEBUG[03-19|12:18:58] Fetching batch of state data             id=597740ce99926a90 conn=inbound count=2
DEBUG[03-19|12:18:58] Peer discarded announcement              peer=2c7bcfec8f6fca6a number=2864444 hash=a1f24e…970159 distance=2864444` here block number is updated  and  I'm also getting imported entries  `INFO [03-19|12:21:44] Imported new state entries               count=806   elapsed=8.085ms      processed=384811 pending=5843  retry=4   duplicate=713 unexpected=1190
`

Answer (score 0):

"At block" should be the one getting updated. As you can see that there are many duplicates and unexpected blocks. These are coming from reorgs and peers sending the same blocks.

You may try following things:

- restarting geth.
- Enable network time synchronization using `timedatectl set-ntp true` and restarting geth.

Currently there is an [open issue](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/15001) regarding syncing problems and there is another related question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/20845/16048).

Comment: I checked timedatectl status and its already enabled..I'll try by restarting geth..

Comment: Guess all I need is to wait until 'known states' gets to 20-25 millions.

Comment: It is recommended to have a SSD instead of HDD. However, if you are unable to sync with geth, you may try using `parity`