# geth never completes syncing for rinkeby

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, rinkeby

My aim is to synchronise a full node for the Rinkeby network.
It seems that geth does not finish synchronisation. I have had it run for over three days, but it is stuck at the last few blocks.

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 4507244,
  highestBlock: 4507319,
  knownStates: 64751595,
  pulledStates: 64748954,
  startingBlock: 4507164
}
> eth.blockNumber
0 
> admin.peers.length
1
> net.peerCount
1
```

When I rerun `eth.syncing`, then the `highestBlock` increases, but `currentBlock` doesn't.

I have tried installing different versions for geth (1.8.X, 1.9.0)
I also enabled network time synchronisation via
`timedatectl set-ntp true`
as suggested in this post: [Geth is stuck syncing](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/20845/geth-is-stuck-syncing)

I run geth via `geth --rinkeby --cache 2048`.

My machine has 12GB RAM and 8 CPUs.

Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try adding `--cache 2048 ` to Geth run command.

Answer (score 1):

Last days I synched my Rinkeby node, the problem is that you are still syncing because you haven't downloaded all the state entries (`pulledStates` and `knownStates`). From now (my node):

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 4507935,
  highestBlock: 4508064,
  knownStates: 90697511,
  pulledStates: 90697511,
  startingBlock: 4507600
}
```

This phase takes a lot longer than the downloading of the blocks.

With the command `geth --rinkeby --cache 2048` you are syncing in default mode (fast). This mode downloads the blocks and the state entries concurrently.

Comment: Are you saying that I simply need to wait longer to complete syncing?

Comment: Maybe, you can read about here (check the HDD related questions): https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16875. I use SSD.

Answer (score 1):

*You will have to be patient to sync a node.*

It took me 60 hours to sync Rinkeby in fast mode. There were **125M state entries** and the folder size was **38GB** after synchronization. With time, both these numbers will grow.

You can type `eth.syncing` in Geth console. If you get 'False' as output, it means that syncing is finished. Otherwise you'll get various details about the blocks and the states.

By typing `eth.blockNumber` you will get the current block number. If the output is 0 then the syncing is not yet complete.

Here is the image when syncing was complete(all the states were pulled) and I started downloading the chain segments.
[Synchronized Rinkeby](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz0E6.jpg)