# Trick to setup node fast - full sync

Tags: go-ethereum

I have a complete node up to date.  If I want a new independent node, I just rsync the complete .etherum dir to another machine, then delete the keysstore and create new account and I'm in businnes.  This is much much much faster than any kind of sync --fast or not. Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use geth `export` and `import` feature.

*Export:*

`geth export <filename>`

*Import:*

`geth import <filename>`

You have to install geth on the machine where you want to import the synced node data. For more detail you can visit [this page](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Backup-&-restore).

Here is the link of answer with benchmarks [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1556/geth-import-vs-copying-chaindata)

Comment: yes, one can do it, but what for? Isn't exporting and re-importing rescanning the entire blockchain for validity (incl. transactions), and as such takes hours, if not days?

Comment: You are right, it may take time while importing. Its make sense lets try to copy and paste :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this answer, I was aware of import and export, but my understanding was that it would take as long as a regular sync (as long as you have a very high bandwidth).  Because the import just saves the download that's all, it still replays the states and everything hence consuming a lot of CPU and time.  The good answer will come from a true benchmark.  I will not make en engagement, but will try to try both and compare elapsed time.