# How to delete or reset the blockchain in geth? (OSX)

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, blocks, mac-osx

I have a currupt Blockchain and want to hard reset the chain. what do I need to delete in order to start downloading the chain from scratch?

I know that there are 2 ethereum folders (I am on OSX):

```
$home/.ethereum
$home/Libary/Ethereum
```

I updated **geth** recently to "Homestead" 1.3.5 and get error in the terminal like:

```
E0306 ... 3211 trie.go:309] Dangling hash node ref 3c6233326.... leveldb: not found
```

and sometimes I get a bad block warning:

```
Bad block #1102797
```

Comment: I updated geth to v 1.3.5, but I also installed eth a while ago (v 1.1.0 / eth newtwork protocol version: 61). I didn't use both a lot just fired them up once in a while

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For geth, delete `$home/Libary/Ethereum/chaindata`. That should wipe out the blockchain itself and let you sync from scratch. Also you probably want to do a fast sync afterwards to get back fast-ish on the chain `--fast`.

Comment: would you start `geth` to reload the chain or direct with `geth --fast`?

Comment: `geth --fast --cache=512 console` is how I would personally start geth :D

Comment: Isn't it more careful to use "geth removedb" instead? It's its purpose.

Comment: For Mac OSX  `rm -R ~/Library/Ethereum/geth/chaindata/`

Comment: `geth removedb`

Answer (score 40):

You can also use `geth removedb` to remove the blockchain and state databases.

```
geth removedb
Remove local database? [y/N]
```

After removing the old databases, run `geth --fast --cache=1024` (see answer to this question by `@eth`).

Note that using `geth --fast` will prevent you from using `debug.traceTransaction(...)` on the blocks that were `--fast` downloaded. Some further information in [How to check the VM trace using Geth?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4282/how-to-check-the-vm-trace-using-geth) and [How can the transaction status from a thrown error be detected when gas can be exactly the same as the gasUsed for a successful transaction?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6007/how-can-the-transaction-status-from-a-thrown-error-be-detected-when-gas-can-be-e).

See also [What is Geth's "fast" sync, and why is it faster?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/what-is-geths-fast-sync-and-why-is-it-faster).

Comment: Also if your pc has more RAM then the --cache=4024 can also be done. And geth --fast can only be used when the blocks database is empty. If you are already downloading the blocks then it is advised not to use geth --fast

Answer (score 22):

[For other operating systems](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/4226/42), the default `datadir` is:

```
Mac: ~/Library/Ethereum
Linux: ~/.ethereum
Windows: %APPDATA%/Ethereum
```

Delete the `chaindata` subdirectory that you find.

Run [`geth --fast --cache=1024`](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/4210/42) for a recommended way to sync the chain quickly (don't forget to use a bigger `--cache` with a value like 1024, otherwise the default is 16, and it won't sync as quickly).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vPi3nMmaunY - shows how to find your %APPDATA% folder in windows 10. For me: %AppData%/Roaming/Ethereum/geth/chaindata