# How can I empty the blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, synchronization, fast-sync

I am trying to do a fast sync using `geth --fast` but I am getting this message:

> blockchain not empty, fast sync disabled

How can I empty the blockchain to allow for fast sync?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**To remove your blockchain with geth, run: `geth removedb`**

**Then:**

Use `--fast` but you probably also need `--cache=1024` (and `--jitvm` may also help). Without it, you are running with the default which is `--cache=16`.

A [50% speed increase](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/4242/42) is possible just by increasing the cache.

If you are starting from the beginning, use: `geth --fast --cache=1024 --jitvm`

Depending on your RAM, you can also try with higher values, like `--cache=2048`.

**NOTE:**
The number after `--cache=` is the amount of memory allocated to the task of downloading the blockchain!!

[Source](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-get-a-geth-node-to-download-the-blockchain-quickly?lq=1)

Comment: Note this should now be `geth removedb` (no dash)

Comment: Is there a way to do this while `geth --fast` is already running? I want to leave it running long-term to answer RPC requests but don't want it to eat up my disk.

Comment: I mean a safe way. You can run `geth removedb` in a separate shell while `geth --fast` is running. I didn't have any problems doing this then sending a few xacts after, but I don't know if it's safe. Docs say nothing.

Answer (score 9):

The default `datadir` is:

```
Mac: ~/Library/Ethereum
Linux: ~/.ethereum
Windows: %APPDATA%/Ethereum
```

Delete the `chaindata` subdirectory that you find.

Run [`geth --fast --cache=1024`](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/4210/42) for a recommended way to sync the chain quickly (don't forget to use a bigger `--cache` with a value like 1024, otherwise the default is 16, and it won't sync as quickly).

EDIT:  Running `geth removedb` is the simplest way to delete the blockchain in Geth.

Answer (score 6):

If you have your blockchain partially or fully imported while starting `geth`, then using the `--fast` flag is ignored (the flag is disabled). To use the `--fast` flag you have to remove all of the data from your `chaindata` folder.

Comment: Will starting fresh with --fast take less time than updating from the stored data? At what point would you say it's worth it?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
geth --fast --cache=2048
```

it seems at least Mac does not provide the other options under go1.9.2:

```
flag provided but not defined: -jitvm
```

Comment: This is an old question (March 2016), early iterations of the `--fast` flag didn't allow restarting geth until it finished syncing, if you did restart it will switch to full mode.