# Not syncing due to "unhandled trie error: missing trie node"

Tags: mist, synchronization

Having an issue. Was caused by Avast blocking a file after I sent some Ether to Dao. Have removed Avast now that I understand it was messing stuff up. Restarted computer... now when i try to sync it says "unhandled trie error: missing trie node" & "invalid receipt root hash"  Running latest version 7.4 of Mist wallet on a mac.  Seems when I sent the ether to dao, Avast blocked some part of the transaction.... now its stuck
Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

As there appears to have been some corruption, now that Avast is off, I would suggest [deleting the chaindata](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2040/42) and then running Mist again.

The default `datadir` is:

```
Mac: ~/Library/Ethereum
Linux: ~/.ethereum
Windows: %APPDATA%/Ethereum
```

Delete the `chaindata` subdirectory that you find.

Comment: Cool... it started syncing again.  thank you for the assistance.

Comment: suppose if the blockchain is private i need data of blockchain too ,  how can be do so . By deleting chaindata we will delete the whole blockchain data in private node.

Comment: @Himanshusharma If you have a copy of the chaindata on another node, try importing it.  If you don't have a copy and the only copy is corrupted, there might be little choice but to reset the chain.  You may want to post a separate question with details from your investigation.