# GETH is always stuck after attempting to sync

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, synchronization, windows

I want to mine Ether and I've been trying to sync blockchains for days.

I've tried using `geth --fast` command and it always stuck as in the picture.

[image: screenshot]

My computer is running 64 bit Windows 10 with geth 1.4.10 installed. I've also tried using `geth --rpc` but it gave me the same result. I'd guessed that it was because my ISP blocks P2P connection but after I try connecting via VPN nothing's changed.

I've already set my time synchronization to be with time.nist.gov as some soln I've found suggest.

Also I have trouble with MIST hang up on 'seeking peers' on startup without any progress.

What should I do to get this stuff done?

Comment: Is `admin.peers` also empty? (I'm assuming it would be if you're stuck "seeking peers".) Ensure that TCP and UDP ports 30303 are forwarded properly through any firewall you might have.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks Yes, `net.peerCount` returns 0. I've manually tried connecting to peer using `admin.addPeer()` but it failed.

Answer (score 2):

I think the clue here is the message "WARNING: Wrote default Ethereum genesis block".

I would try renaming the default datadir (see [Not syncing due to "unhandled trie error: missing trie node"](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4245/not-syncing-due-to-unhandled-trie-error-missing-trie-node/4246#4246) for paths) then try `geth --fast console`.

You can copy the keystore within the datadir from your old datadir to your new datadir to save your accounts. And if successful, then remove your old renamed datadir

Alternatively you can try running `geth removedb` to remove the blockchain and state database. Then run `geth --fast console`.

---

## The Warning

The warning is emitted from [go-ethereum - eth/backend.go, lines 239-248](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/eth/backend.go#L239-L248), and it seems that `geth` cannot find the genesis block so it writes a new one. The source code follows:

```
// load the genesis block or write a new one if no genesis
// block is prenent in the database.
genesis := core.GetBlock(chainDb, core.GetCanonicalHash(chainDb, 0))
if genesis == nil {
    genesis, err = core.WriteDefaultGenesisBlock(chainDb)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    glog.V(logger.Info).Infoln("WARNING: Wrote default ethereum genesis block")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for respond! What should I name the defaultdir ?  I've already try `removedb` before I post the question but it didn't help.

Comment: I usually rename my directory {old directory name}_pre_20160723 . The `removedb` will remove the chain data, but not the configs.