# Error: missing trie node 60c376cdb14aec... (path)

Tags: go-ethereum, rinkeby

I'm trying to start a geth node to connect to the Rinkeby test network by running

```
geth --networkid=4 --datadir=$HOME/.rinkeby --verbosity 0 --syncmode=light 
--bootnodes=enode://a24ac7c5484ef4ed0c5eb2d36620ba4ea13b8c84684e1b4aab0cebea2ae45cb4d375b77eab56516d34bfbd3c1a833fc51296ff084b770b94fb9028c4d25ccf@52.169.42.101:30303?discport=30304 --rpc 
--rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi=eth,web3,net,personal,ssh,db,debug --unlock="0xf905463ebd62121b16e0076cadc19a7b0e706c77" console
```

which has always worked fine (btw I'm aware of security concerns with the command but I don't really care about that for now). However, despite starting still, if I run

```
eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])
```

I get back an error

```
Error: missing trie node 60c376cdb14aec29386df043d081afcfa38a97da22e25d344c4104fd91cf6cc1 (path )
    at web3.js:3104:20
    at web3.js:6191:15
    at web3.js:5004:36
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

[This](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4245/not-syncing-due-to-unhandled-trie-error-missing-trie-node) answer suggests removing the blockchain for a similar issue, but I'd like to avoid that since it took a while to download it the first time around. Any ideas how to solve this and why this started happening?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/7791/48828) could be useful for you. That error could mean data corruption, that's why it is suggested to delete the chain data.