# Geth Fast Sync imports blocks that have already been synced

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

I keep having this problem where geth fast syncs normally importing headers and receipts (not blocks) up until a certain point at which it starts importing blocks that I had already synced a long time ago.

An example of the output is as follows (the most recent time this happened):

```
I0524 14:22:07.798880 core/headerchain.go:294] imported 192 header(s) (0 ignored) in 2.469281116s. #660378 [2073f529… / 3a505033…]
I0524 14:22:08.209943 core/blockchain.go:751] imported 6 receipt(s) (0 ignored) in 21.040595ms. #660192 [2073f529… / 454b2b4f…]
I0524 14:22:16.408611 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1130] Rolled back 2048 headers (LH: 660378->658330, FB: 660192->658330, LB: 0->0)
I0524 14:22:17.484047 core/blockchain.go:751] imported 103 receipt(s) (0 ignored) in 512.848247ms. #660295 [07662877… / 02d566a8…]
I0524 14:22:17.922178 core/blockchain.go:751] imported 83 receipt(s) (0 ignored) in 372.939255ms. #660378 [779d2a58… / 3a505033…]
I0524 14:22:34.658717 core/headerchain.go:294] imported 0 header(s) (192 ignored) in 68.916111ms. #192 [88e96d45… / 723899e8…]
I0524 14:23:09.703319 core/blockchain.go:959] imported 2 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 0 txs in 34.853133777s. #2 [88e96d45 / b495a1d7]
I0524 14:23:09.793493 core/headerchain.go:294] imported 0 header(s) (192 ignored) in 84.786686ms. #384 [967642fd… / d3d5d5c1…]
I0524 14:23:14.549250 core/blockchain.go:959] imported 190 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 0 txs in 4.74805811s. #192 [3d612266 / 723899e8]
I0524 14:23:14.599539 core/headerchain.go:294] imported 0 header(s) (192 ignored) in 44.800954ms. #576 [bbb506ab… / 41a7466b…]
I0524 14:23:19.567974 core/blockchain.go:959] imported 192 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 0 txs in 4.949800668s. #384 [967642fd / d3d5d5c1]
I0524 14:23:19.665313 core/headerchain.go:294] imported 0 header(s) (192 ignored) in 78.182567ms. #768 [c4cee3bf… / 5cfe57c2…]
```

It goes on (somewhat later) to sync only the blocks.

This has been really frustrating in trying to catch up (in this latest instance it went from block #660378 to #192; other times have been comparable to this and sometimes it has happened when I was even further along), and I could really use any help on how to go about fixing this.

Feel free to ask me any questions that might help you diagnose and hopefully fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this "looping" behavior in the past and I would suggest [deleting the `chaindata`](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2040/how-can-i-empty-the-blockchain-to-allow-for-fast-sync) and then running [`geth --fast --cache=1024`](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/4210/42).

The default datadir is:

```
Mac: ~/Library/Ethereum
Linux: ~/.ethereum
Windows: %APPDATA%/Ethereum
```

Delete the `chaindata` subdirectory that you find.

Comment: I've done just that repeatedly and still get the same error.

Comment: Try http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4304/where-can-i-go-if-i-still-have-problems-with-syncing-the-blockchain

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your question, but I would like to encourage client diversity and you could try out the parity client in fast pruning mode which is considered very stable:

```
$ parity --pruning fast
```

http://parity.io - Maybe this could be an alternative for you to consider.