# Rolled back headers dropping the peer right after. geth 1.6.0

Tags: blockchain, block-header

As you can see in this picture I get the same problem over and over again. Headers aren't downloading, they always roll back to header # 1379306.
[image]

Does any body know what would be the problem here?

Comment: This looks very similar to https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4268/geth-fast-sync-imports-blocks-that-have-already-been-synced. The suggestion is that if you're still having problems then you should follow the further instructions here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4304/where-can-i-go-if-i-still-have-problems-with-syncing-the-blockchain