# Synchronisation failed Invalid old chain

Tags: mining, blockchain, mining-pools

I got this error "Synchronisation failed: Invalid old chain" I tried `geth removedb` and `geth upgradedb` but I got the same error again any help please?

Comment: Are you running the most recent version of geth?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try deleting and reimporting your blockchain as described in [How to delete or reset the blockchain in geth? (OSX)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1897/how-to-delete-or-reset-the-blockchain-in-geth) .

You should be able to rename your blockchain directory and then delete it when you have successfully re-created your blockchain.

Comment: Just make sure you do `--fast`. It makes a world of a difference.