# Blockchain sync on geth stalls at block 1.1 million

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, synchronization, homestead, forks

I saw the responses on a few issues regarding ethereum and blockchain sync on this site, and was wondering if anyone could help me with a problem I'm facing.

I've been trying to sync the blockchain with Geth for the past week now and have only managed to get to block 1.1 million. Though initially I enjoyed download speeds of a few second per 256 blocks, speeds have dropped to more than two min per 256 blocks over the last two days. The download keeps breaking off every 15 min with error - not enough peers.

I have tried everything from syncing system clock with time.nist.gov, enabled port forwarding to 30303, turned antivirus and firewall off etc.. but all in vain.

Is there a way to use the `admin.addPeer` command and connect to active nodes ? Where could i find a list of fully synced active node? Or is there any other way I could try and speed the blockchain sync up?

Any constructive advise would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ethereum Stack Exchange. Which version are you using? There was [a hard fork at block 1,150,000](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/02/29/homestead-release/) so make sure you are using the latest version of geth.

Comment: Iv got the latest geth 1.3.6, installed on win7 64 bit OS.

Comment: @Dhruv_9 There is also an "edit" link where you can add further details to your question.

Comment: If you get stuck over and over again, [resetting your blockchain](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1897/87) might be the solution.

Comment: do you mean using removedb to nuke the db and start from scratch ? gosh that ll be painful to do to a weeks strenuous work..

Comment: isn't there a way to manually add peers ? since thats what geth keeps complaining about - no peers to keep download active..

Comment: @ 5chdn I followed suite and reset the blockchain to run --fast sync. Iv managed to catch up to the latest block and am now witnessing state side entries being imported in lots ranging from 1 - 50 entries. This has been on for some time now (over two hours) and transactions processed keeps resetting back to block 0 every now and then ... is this normal? how long could i expect this to go on till?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

took forever for me as well, with lots of timouts, but started again but never got fully stuck.

I used 
geth --rpc --nat=none --cache=2024

this then did speed things  up a bit, but still took days.

to confirm you have synced
open seperate cmd and 
geth attach
eth.syncing

to confirm how far behind you are.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

I have meet the similar situation. After many try and test, I found that Hard disk have key impact. And change the disk to RAID or SSD (both are OK), the problem is resolve. The Blockchain sync up to top do not need more time. Hope this info can help someone.