# Evaluate the performance of a smart contract

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs, testing, truffle-test

What is the best way and tools to evaluate the performance of a smart contract. More specifically, I want to test my contract for large scale deployment by making a script that emulate real world interaction scenarios with the contract.

Any hints about how to create such a script test? should I use web3.js or truffle framework test? How to program thousand of transactions to be sent to the blockchain? and what are the relevant metrics that I could measure after the test.

Thanks.

Comment: See: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5957/solidity-benchmarking-metrics?rq=1 (And the question it's duplicated to.)

Answer (score 2):

The only metric I really care about is cost to deployment.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/eth-gas-reporter

quite possibly, efficiency, but that can cause other problems with the breaking changes in solidity V0.5.0