# Custom Exceptions in Solidity

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, contract-development, mist, exceptions

In solidity, is there any way  to throw `custom Exceptions` along with error messages? I am using `throw` to prevent further execution of my code but this always results in `invalid JUMP`(in geth console, on debugging) and `Intrinsic gas too low` (in Mist).Can I have custom error messages?
 
For example can we modify `transfer(..)` function to produce error message `account balance is low` when balance of sender is less than amount he wants to transfer?

```
 function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {

    if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value)        // Check if the sender has enough
{
        throw;  
        // some code to display  "account balance is low" to  user instead of 'Intrinsic Gas too low'
}

    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                     // Subtract from the sender
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);                // Notify anyone listening that this transfer took  

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently there are no custom exceptions in Ethereum Virtual Machine code. All failure conditions are "out of gas" as exception is modelled as consuming all the remaining gas.

[eth.debug.traceTransaction API may give you some insight](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4282/how-to-check-the-vm-trace-using-geth/4289#4289), but it doesn't implement human readable error mechanisms at the moment as far as I know.

Comment: Technically, `throw` results in an "Invalid Jump" error, not an out of gas error, but the result is the same.

Comment: That's strange. I mean whatever be the reason of failure of transaction user will always get `Invalid Jump`. Becomes quite unhandy to our users.

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh: This is a known issue. The original protocol was developed simplicity in mind and I believe the future Ethereum versions will address this.

Comment: Please note that this is 2016 answer.

Answer (score 1):

From solidity 0.4.22, It is possible to add error messages with `require` and `assert`. `throw` is deprecated. It took long time but finally adding an error statement is possible. [Refrence](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.22)

A sample contract using this is illustrated as:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;
contract TestExceptionHandling{
    uint public a ;
    constructor(uint _a) public{
        a= _a;
    }
    function increaseA(uint b) public{
        require(b > a, 'new value must be greater than a');
        if (b > 50){
            revert('Very large value');
        }
        a = b;
    }
}
```

I am not sure of How to catch this error message in DAPP and show the error message to UI. Will update the answer when I have explored that.

Answer (score 1):

As of now you can throw an error like this. I am not sure when it was added:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

/// Write custom Error!
error MyCustomError();
```

It is 3 "///". "Write custom Error!" is the message that will be shown to the user

then call it in your function

```
   if (thisIsNotSatisfied){
          revert MyCustomError()
      }
```