# geth console flag/option to output all opcodes executed in call to contract or function invocation

Tags: evm, opcode, bytecode

What I'd like to do is analyze all the opcodes that are executed when I call a contract, or call a function from a contract.

According to my understanding, this computation would happen on my own machine, in the `EVM`, and only the result would be sent to the blockchain.

My idea is that, for this result to be calculated, the computations have to run on my local machine at some point in the following process:

```
var contractAbi = eth.contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getPeople","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"},{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"},{"name":"","type":"uint256[]"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_firstName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_lastName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_age","type":"uint256"}],"name":"addPerson","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"people","outputs":[{"name":"firstName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"lastName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"age","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"}]);

undefined

var myContract = contractAbi.at("0xC127E3ca071892B1b471b4FC568312Fcbb737879");

undefined

var getData = myContract.addPerson.getData("S. Matthew", "English", 28);

undefined

personal.unlockAccount(eth.coinbase, 'hunter2');

web3.eth.sendTransaction({to:"0xC127E3ca071892B1b471b4FC568312Fcbb737879", from:"0xd7a9a61a480d458a1181e0563b07f944df4489a6", data: getData, gas: (270000)});

"0x0cec118d22fbd572bf25c7e4143919e608989bec7da08512f2a6f3171df3b3b8"

myContract.address

"0xC127E3ca071892B1b471b4FC568312Fcbb737879"

myContract.getPeople()

[["0x532e204d61747468657700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"], ["0x456e676c69736800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"], [28]]

myContract.getPeople().toLocaleString()

"0x532e204d61747468657700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,0x456e676c69736800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,28"
```

How can I observe the opcodes that are being executed as a consequence of the above sequence?

Using the [ByteCode To Opcode Disassembler](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/opcode-tool) on Etherscan I've seen which opcodes are invoked on contract creation, but I imagine that this is different than just calling a contract or one of it's functions, since- for instance, you won't need to invoke the constructor again, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `debug.traceTransaction(...)`.

Example from Mainnet:

```
> debug.traceTransaction("0xe7cdf3ddebd6b1f3c21b26346da52901b6035b39bdfb58de49491b47a92808a7")
{
  gas: 30981,
  returnValue: "",
  structLogs: [{
      depth: 1,
      error: null,
      gas: 13725,
      gasCost: 3,
      memory: null,
      op: "PUSH1",
      pc: 0,
      stack: [],
      storage: {}
  }, {
      depth: 1,
      error: null,
      gas: 13722,
      gasCost: 3,
      memory: null,
      op: "PUSH1",
      pc: 2,
      stack: ["0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060"],
      storage: {}
  }, {
  ...
  }, {
      depth: 1,
      error: null,
      gas: 4019,
      gasCost: 1,
      memory: ["0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060", "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000015a1fa6f11a5551"],
      op: "JUMPDEST",
      pc: 80,
      stack: ["00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f7654176"],
      storage: {}
  }, {
      depth: 1,
      error: null,
      gas: 4019,
      gasCost: 0,
      memory: ["0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060", "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000015a1fa6f11a5551"],
      op: "STOP",
      pc: 81,
      stack: ["00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f7654176"],
      storage: {}
  }]
}
```

Comment: so, it doesn't cost any gas to run that? I can do it for any transaction? where does it get that data from?

Comment: It does not cost gas to run. You can do it for any transaction as long as your `geth` blockchain data contains the full transaction data. If you `--fast` sync your blockchain, the full transaction data will be unavailable before the block that is fast synced. See also https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4282/how-to-check-the-vm-trace-using-geth/4289#4289 and https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6007/how-can-the-transaction-status-from-a-thrown-error-be-detected-when-gas-can-be-e/6011#6011

Comment: so then there's just like- hundreds of thousands, even millions, of `JSON` objects on every full node with all this opcode data on them?

Comment: ah so, sort of relatedly, we could probably call this function in a more specialized way, for instance- only to get the opcodes, leave the rest of that stuff, isn't it?

Comment: haha ok- last question for these comments- is it possible to see how long each opcode takes to execute?