# Deinstall geth builded from source completely together with the blockchain and every piece of data

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, build-from-source

I use Lubuntu 17.10.

I have followed the steps in the tutorial to **build** geth from **source**. ([here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-Instructions-for-Ubuntu#building-from-source))

I have **abandoned** the idea of **mining** ether with my crappy hardware.

How can I **deinstall** the big fat **blockchain** and every single piece of data that goes with the source install, that eats up my limited space on my precious hard drive?

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1897/how-to-delete-or-reset-the-blockchain-in-geth-osx

Comment: possible not duplicate see edit