# Sent ETH to my Wallet, but it did not show up

Tags: transactions, mist, synchronization

*Note: This question was initially asked for Mist, but is in general also true for all other wallets like Ethereum Wallet, Etherwall, Parity, Harmony, etc.*

---

I sent ETH from MyEtherWallet to my Mist Wallet, but balance did not show the sent amount. Later, I also imported MyEtherWallet account into Mist.

The transaction detail showing the amount that was sent to my Mist wallet below: https://etherscan.io/address/0x5C8a1cbEF21403B2D708796ea2F050F517393b91

Attached is a screenshot showing the 0 balance in my Mist wallet. I presume the blockchain is fully synced as I can see my Accounts Overview.

Any idea how I can use the amount that was sent to my Mist Wallet.

[image]

Comment: Your ether won't show up until Mist has finished syncing. Ignore the elapsed time of 47 years - you've never downloaded any blocks, so it's showing time since the epoch. First thing to do would be to check that your Mac's clock is correct. Then check both your Mac and home router are allowing traffic on ports 30301 and 30303...

Answer (score 4):

The ethers will not appear in your account until you have downloaded the blockchain to the block number containing your transaction. Let the blockchain sync. 
You can use `--fast --cache=1024` for faster downloading the blockchain. Refer [How can I get a geth node to download the blockchain quickly?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-get-a-geth-node-to-download-the-blockchain-quickly/4210).

If you want to use your ethers urgently, you can use platforms like [MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#send-transaction) to import your private keys. But it's up to you if you don't want to trust a third party, better wait and let your blockchain to sync completely.

Answer (score 3):

You can see at the top of the screen there are 575,615 blocks left to sync, so wait until it is fully synced.

Comment: Thanks Bokky. I thought my Mist wallet account went amiss.  As this is my first time using the Mist wallet app, the syncing process has taken longer than expected (more than 1 hour) and it is still in process.  If there is an alternative method to use/send the amount of ETH that was deposited in my Mist wallet, please let me know.  I tried importing the private key of my Mist wallet account using MyEtherWallet, but it was not successful to unlock the wallet (taking a long time in processing).

Answer (score 3):

Only after completing sync will Ethereum Wallet 0.8.7 display your accounts and your balance. I waited for sync to complete (literally days); then finally it displayed my account names and addresses, balances and total balance.

Answer (score 2):

Transactions and balances will not show up (or show up incorrectly) in Mist until it is fully synced. Essentially, without syncing, the wallet user interface cannot display what has happened as it doesn't yet know that it has happened. It gets all its data from the blockchain.

So, if you sent 1 ETH to a wallet that you are viewing in mist on April 1st, but the blockchain is only synced up to December 1st, Mist doesn't know that the transaction as happened yet and believes the balance is 0.

Additionally, if you sent 1 ETH from your mist account to another one on April 1st, but it is only synced to December 1st, the interface may still show you have your original balance, when you actually have 1 ETH less than your current balance.

Comment: Thanks Tay.  If there is an alternative method to use/send the amount of ETH that was deposited in my Mist wallet, please let me know. I tried importing the private key of my Mist wallet account using MyEtherWallet, but it was not successful to unlock the wallet (taking a long time in processing).

Comment: You can access your Mist wallet in MyEtherWallet. Find the keystore directory via accounts -> backup -> accounts and select that `UTC-.....` file on MyEtherWallet. Both Mist and MyEtherWallet are just accessing an account. You can use both clients to access and send the same account via the private key (the keystore file).

Answer (score 2):

You need peers to download the blockchain. You can wait for Mist to find peers, or you can add them manually. This [page](https://www.reddit.com/r/EthereumClassic/comments/5kw8jv/trouble_finding_peers_with_geth_try_adding_this/) has an example. For this to work, you should either replace your `.ethereum/static-nodes.json` file with [this one](https://www.epool.io/static-nodes.json), or start Geth with the following parameters:

```
$ geth --bootnodes enode://pubkey1@ip1:port1, enode://pubkey2@ip2:port
```

In case the links are removed, the json file should look like this:

```
[
"enode://e3aa041cf419f15e317c96cf04b2ccdfc6aa9ac45e75c2acabfceba908fc080fb424c5f36e3279b9675ccd85739ffbbbca94501f48ddae4cf7870235077c013d@78.46.49.102:30304",
"enode://10a23a68bb889dee3ae27cb752dc118e864a0c688483e6a0af947466ec22bef8b54d5c93fa6d5cd7dea038a778622fb23d4738785f080f29cbbeef594a3ec1ac@79.237.109.206:30303",
"enode://9ae95140c39cf0916012cb49b45ee7f7c25b9fb31d4ae8b560f2dd0d8325d37489e1a89aa75f6c977791a9925005012803b939eafdf97b6c5095728d97a3bb75@52.58.139.58:30303"
]
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @5chdn I updated the answer accordingly.