# Ethereum Wallet downloading blocks - How to handle that memory size?

Tags: blockchain, wallets

I'm syncing the Ethereum node for a while now. It almost finished, but I gradually need to delete files, because it'd barely fits my disk. I only have an iMac with a 256 GB SSD and ethereum takes like 75% or so of it :/
Is this normal? Do other people struggle with this or is it just me having a small hard disk? I also have a SD card with 64 GB free, could I transfer it there? I'm also concerned not to lose my 10 ETH.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Parity](https://parity.io) only requires around 10 GB of disk space.

Comment: I second the use of Parity. Also, I would recommend against using most SD cards if for no other reason than, unless you've got a fast one, the syncing process could be rather painful in terms of speed unless you leave the Ethereum client running all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `--fast` option while syncing. The fast sync is really faster and the blockchain data occupies less space on your hard disk because:

> Instead of processing the entire blockchain one link at a time, and
>   replay all transactions that ever happened in history, fast syncing
>   downloads the transaction receipts along with the blocks, and pulls an
>   entire recent state database.

But you can't mix both normal and fast sync. Either you download the whole blockchain using fast way (`--fast`) or the normal way. 
See: [How can I get a geth node to download the blockchain quickly?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-get-a-geth-node-to-download-the-blockchain-quickly)

> I'm also concerned not to lose my 10 ETH.

You need not worry about your ethers. Just [backup](http://backup) your ethereum-wallet. **Pay attention**: It's always safe to keep backup before making any changes to `.ethereum` directory

Answer (score 0):

Yes, storing the blockchain takes tens of gigabytes of storage. You don't need to run a full node however if you just want to see your wallet and send Ether. As Prashant said, you can use the `--fast` flag.

There are alternatives that use drastically less storage. [MyEtherWallet.com](http://myetherwallet.com), and [Parity](https://parity.io/) are the two that I recommend.