# What does 'startingBlock` mean in `eth.syncing`

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

First time `geth` user here. I'm trying to do some analysis on transactions on the mainnet and for that I need all the blocks since the beginning of time. When I just ran `geth` with no parameters, it looks like it is starting from only block 3280013 but I want it to start from block 1:

EDIT: I am looking for clarification of what startingBlock means, not how to download the whole blockchain and how `--fast` helps. This is not a duplicate.

[image]

Will it still work and will I get block data from the beginning of time?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a geth node to download the blockchain quickly?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-get-a-geth-node-to-download-the-blockchain-quickly)

Comment: Not a duplicate, OP has self-answered, with a completely different answer from the linked dupe answer.

Answer (score 5):

Straight from the docs [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.9/web3-eth.html#eth-issyncing-return)

> Returns
>
> Object|Boolean - A sync object as follows, when the node is currently
> syncing or false:
>
> **startingBlock**: **Number - The block number where the sync started.**
> currentBlock: Number - The block number where at which block the node
> currently synced to already. highestBlock: Number - The estimated
> block number to sync to.

So it has nothing to do with the block from which `geth` will sync but rather the block at which the sync started. For instance, if you stopped syncing at 3500000 exclusive by turning your node off and then resumed, your `startingBlock` would be 3500000.