# how to make geth import faster?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, network, import

my computer is mac and it has run geth import for about a week, and it's 4000000 block now. I have ran geth --fast before and it's slow too. I am in china, is it something i can do to make it faster?

Comment: Add `--cache=1024` per this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-get-a-geth-node-to-download-the-blockchain-quickly

Comment: Are you using a SSD? It is required to sync.

Comment: download exported blockchain from the net, import it, and then just sync the remaining blocks.

Comment: i figure out that i should clean the database before i run geth --fast, but now it print INFO [12-03|19:59:43] Imported new state entries               count=919  elapsed=30.270ms  processed=25441830 pending=8841  retry=47   duplicate=8575 unexpected=23362
WARN [12-03|19:59:58] Stalling state sync, dropping peer       peer=107d9b0f9f47fbca and never end, is it ok?

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
geth removedb
```

then

```
geth --light
```

I have found that --light is much faster, only a few minutes for me compared to fast.

Comment: with your recommendation to `removedb` he will lose the week he was downloading. and the --light option won't download the full blockchain btw, only current state

Comment: Yes he will delete his chain, but will have a fully synced chain in minutes giving him access to his funds and enabling him to start transacting.  Why would you need a full node when the average person only needs to access their wallet.  Since --light became available its all I use.

Comment: you are right. i do geth removedb, then geth --fast. i read the document that say fast mode only works when there is no data in database.