# Ethereum light node: Light vs Cache vs fastsync

Tags: nodes

There are many different options when running a Ethereum node. I want to make sure I pick the right options before I start downloading the blockchain... can someone explain the advantages of using:

—light
—cache
—fastsync

I’m not sure which ones to use and I don’t want to break anything. The main purpose of my node is to act as wallet for my website that accepts Ether, so for example if this was a bitcoin node I’d enable pruning as I don’t need the entire blockchain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- "Full" Sync: Gets the block headers, the block bodies, and validates every element from genesis block.
- Fast Sync: Gets the block headers, the block bodies, it processes no transactions until current block - 64(*). Then it gets a snapshot state and goes like a full synchronization.
- Light Sync: Gets only the current state. To verify elements, it needs to ask to full (archive) nodes for the corresponding tree leaves.

**Then an extra piece of information on cache and how it can used to go fast from [this response](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-get-a-geth-node-to-download-the-blockchain-quickly/4210?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa):**

A 50% speed increase is possible just by increasing the cache.

If you are starting from the beginning, use: geth --fast --cache=1024

If you already have some of the blockchain, use: geth --cache=1024

Depending on your RAM, you can also try with higher values, like --cache=2048.